# Which is the main clause in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

> Was mich unbedingt noch interessiert ist, ob es bei der Diagnose dieser Krankheit bestimmte Zeitvorgaben gibt.

Which of the two sentences is the "Hauptsatz" and which is the "Nebensatz"? The verb is coming at the end of both!

Comment: In my opinion there should be a comma between *interessiert* and *ist* which should make things clearer.

Comment: you are totally right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an answer to the original question but to the following question you posted as comment to Stephie's answer:

> Why this construction is wrong?
>
> > Was interessiert mich unbedingt noch, ob es bei der Diagnose dieser Krankheit bestimmte Zeitvorgaben gibt.

This sentence is actually an abbreviation of:

> **Das**, was mich unbedingt noch interressiert, ist, ob es ...

When we look at the elements of the sentence we have:

> [[Das][, was mich unbedingt noch interessiert,]] [ist] [, ob es ...]

The first element of the main clause consists of two sub-elements: The word "*Das*" and a **relative clause** describing the word "*Das*".

So actually you have **two** relative clauses in this sentence:

> - was mich unbedingt noch interessiert
> - ob es bei der Diagnose dieser Krankheit bestimmte Zeitvorgaben gibt.

You can see that the verb ("*interessiert*", "*gibt*") is the last element of each of these relative clauses.

You could of course re-word the sentence in a way that "*interessieren*" is the verb of the main clause:

> Mich interessiert unbedingt noch, ob es ...

The word "*Was*" is no longer present then.

Answer (score 9):

If you are ordering two elements, the second will also be the last. Look at your example:

> [Was mich unbedingt noch interessiert] [ist],

Mentally replace the first bracket with “Das” and it becomes more obvious:

> [Das] [ist],

There’s your main clause.

And

> [ob] [es] [bei der Diagnose dieser Krankheit] [bestimmte Zeitvorgaben] [gibt].

Finite verb at the end: Subordinate clause.

Comment: Why this construction is wrong? Was interessiert mich unbedingt noch, ob es bei der Diagnose dieser Krankheit bestimmte Zeitvorgaben gibt.

Comment: @Millen It's not easy to explain why this is not correct, but if you translate it to English it becomes something like "What I am urgently interested in if there are certain time restrictions with the diagnosis of this disease." So you can see that there is something missing in this sentence. By the way, if you interpret the sentence as colloquial German where 'was' is synonymous to 'warum' it would become sort of correct.

Comment: @Millen that’s basically another question if you can explain why a grammar book couldn’t help you.